# jenkins parameter From Properties file

Tags: jenkins, parameters, properties

I have 3 Jenkins jobs to be run in serial.

1. Run a Ant File
2. Run another ANT File
3. Run a command line

All the above jobs use a file path which is set in a properties file.
Ex Job 1 , Executes ANT file placed in file path location
Job 2 , Executes another file placed in same file path location
Job 3 , Executes command line to do SVN update in same file path location

I need to parameterize the file path in all three builds from properties file.

Can anyone help me with possible approach?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

This answer could be a little high level. You can use [Jenkins Pipeline as a code](https://jenkins.io/solutions/pipeline/) for this approach instead of using 3 freestyle jobs.

You can create 3 [stages](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/#stage) which performs these 3 steps. Pipeline as a code supports [reading of properties](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#code-readproperties-code-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text) from different file types (json, yaml etc.)

Answer (score 0):

Look for the "EnvInject" plugin.  This lets you inject properties into your build as environment variables; these assignments survive build step boundaries.

If the property file is checked in, you can load it in the Build Environment section before the build steps start executing.  If the property file is generated during the build sequence, you can add a build step between where the property file is created and where it is used.

Once set, if the property file contains "FOO=/path/to/folder" then in configuring Jenkins things you would refer to $FOO or ${FOO} (for example, an Ant build step might specify "${FOO}/build.xml"; in Windows batch script execution FOO shows up as an environment variable and is referenced by %FOO% (i.e., "@echo Some_Useful_Piece_Of_Data > %FOO%\data.txt"

More information can be found here: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin